# Credit card processing: duplicate data 1 with # one empty

Tags: magento, braintree

I have magento 1.8 with a 1.7 ves_t-shirt theme installed.

I have Swift Checkout and onestepcheckout

The problem is that after hitting “Purchase” the credit card data is getting posted twice.

```
payment[cc_cid] 567
payment[cc_cid]
payment[cc_exp_month] 6
payment[cc_exp_year] 2016
payment[cc_number] 4111111111111
payment[cc_number]
payment[cc_type] VI
payment[method] braintree
```

this is the post data from firebug. You can see that the CID and CC# are being posted twice. The second is blank which then triggers this error:

There was an error capturing the transaction. (Transaction declined: Credit card number is required. Credit card must include either number or venmo_sdk_payment_method_code. Credit card type is not accepted by this merchant account.)

Can anyone tell me how to stop the second set of data?

Comment: I work at Braintree. If the Braintree extension is working correctly, the credit card data being posted should be encrypted, and if that somehow doesn't work, no credit card data should get posted at all. It's possible you need to change the order of your extensions, and Swift Checkout may not be compatible with Braintree's extension.